# How do I add text to the bottom left of each page?

Tags: formatting

I'd like to add text "`Prepared for Name, Surname`" at the bottom left on each page of the PDF document. Anyone knows how to do it easily?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [background](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\SetBgContents{Prepared for Name, Surname}
\SetBgScale{2}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgColor{blue}
\SetBgPosition{current page.south west}
\SetBgHshift{3cm}
\SetBgVshift{1cm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I could place it simply in the footer of the page using `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyfoot[L]{Prepared for Name, Surname}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

If you don't want to do this, put place the text further into the edge you can use `tikz` which allows you to place text anywhere on the page if you set the `remember picture,overlay` options. See the example on page 200 of the v2.10 PGF/TikZ manual (`pgfmanual`). Any text or drawing would be possible. For your text it would be:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
...

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node [xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm] at (current page.south west)
    [above right]
        {Prepared for Name, Surname}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, this only places the text on the current page. You need to repeat it for every page. You can do this by placing the code in the footer or header or by using recursive `\afterpage` trick shown in [How can I change the increment of the page numbering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11393/how-can-i-change-the-increment-of-the-page-numbering/11394#11394).

```
\newcommand\preparedfor{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm] at (current page.south west)
      [above right]
          {Prepared for Name, Surname}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \afterpage{\preparedfor}%
}
\begin{document}
\preparedfor
....
```

Comment: The `fancyhdr` approach will not work (as it is now) for those pages (first page of each chapter using `book` or `report`, for example) that internally use a style different from `fancy`. The TikZ approach can be more easily achieved (in my opiniom) with the `backgound` package (which internally, in fact, uses TikZ).