# Putting [Turn over at the end of a page

Tags: exam, page, footer

How to put the phrase **[Turn over** at the end of the first page (and the subsequent odd numbered pages) of the following code. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\noprintanswers
%\printanswers

\pointsinmargin 
%\pointsinrightmargin
%\bracketedpoints
\boxedpoints
%\noboxedpoints
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102066/how-to-insert-logo-in-exam-document-class
\parindent=0pt 
\title{\begin{picture}(0,0)\unitlength=1cm
    \put (-5,-1) {\includegraphics[width=5em]{example-image-a}}
    \end{picture}UNIVERSITY OF MALTA\\FACULTY OF SCIENCE \vspace{-1em}}
\author{Department of Mathematics\\B.SC.(Hons.) YEAR 1\\January 2013 Examination Session\\MAT1511 Analytical Geometry \qquad January 25, 2016}
\date{11.45 a.m. - 1.45 p.m }

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Answer THREE QUESTIONS
\hrule


\newpage


Page 2

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `fancyhdr` work?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18713/28557

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\firstpagefooter
  {}
  {}
  {\textbf{[Turn over}}
\runningfooter
  {}
  {Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
  {\ifodd\value{page}
    \ifnum\value{page}<\numpages\textbf{[Turn over}\fi
  \fi}
```

and `\thispagestyle{headandfoot}` next to `\maketitle`.

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\noprintanswers
%\printanswers

\pointsinmargin 
%\pointsinrightmargin
%\bracketedpoints
\boxedpoints
%\noboxedpoints
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102066/how-to-insert-logo-in-exam-document-class
\parindent=0pt 
\title{\begin{picture}(0,0)\unitlength=1cm
    \put (-5,-1) {\includegraphics[width=5em]{example-image-a}}
    \end{picture}UNIVERSITY OF MALTA\\FACULTY OF SCIENCE \vspace{-1em}}
\author{Department of Mathematics\\B.SC.(Hons.) YEAR 1\\January 2013 Examination Session\\MAT1511 Analytical Geometry \qquad January 25, 2016}
\date{11.45 a.m. - 1.45 p.m }

% footer:
\firstpagefooter
  {}
  {}
  {\textbf{[Turn over}}
\runningfooter
  {}
  {Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
  {\ifodd\value{page}
    \ifnum\value{page}<\numpages\textbf{[Turn over}\fi
  \fi}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{headandfoot}% <- added
Answer THREE QUESTIONS
\hrule

\newpage
Page 2
\newpage
Page 3
\newpage
Page 4
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]